# using a vector of column names, to generate a sql statement

Tags: c++, sql, idioms

A problem that we need to solve regularly at my workplace is how to build sql statements based on user supplied table/column names.  The issue I am trying to address is the commas between column names.

One technique looks something like this.

```
selectSql  = "SELECT ";

for (z = 0; z < columns.size(); z++)
{
    selectSql += columns[z]._name;
    selectSql += ", "; 
}

selectSql = selectSql(0, selectSql.len() - 2);

selectSql += "FROM some-table";
```

Another technique looks something like this

```
selectSql  = "SELECT ";

for (z = 0; z < columns.size(); z++)
{
    selectSql += columns[z]._name;
    if (z < columns.size() - 1) 
        selectSql += ", "; 
}

selectSql += "FROM some-table";
```

I am not particularly enthralled by either of these implementations.

I am interesting in hearing ideas for other ways to address this issue, with an eye toward making the code easier to read/understand/maintain.

What alternate techniques are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it is probably safe to assume that there is at least one column since otherwise there is no point in doing the select.  In that case you could do:

```
selectSql  = "SELECT ";
selectSql += columns[0]._name;

for (z = 1; z < columns.size(); z++) {
   selectSql += ", ";
   selectSql += columns[z]._name;
}

selectSql += " FROM some-table";
```

Comment: Looks clean too, with no tests.

Comment: The for loop implicitly has a test :)

Comment: I refer of course to extra tests within the body of the loop, or additional processing outside the loop, to remove the final comma :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than applying a work around each time again, you can fix the problem once and for all by writing a function object, and using that like strager proposed (though his implementation is rather not C++):

```
struct join {
    std::string sep;
    join(std::string const& sep): sep(sep) { }

    template<typename Column>
    std::string operator()(Column const& a, Column const& b) const {
        return a._name + sep + b._name;
    }
};
```

As i don't know your column type, i've left it templated. Now, whenever you want to build a query, just do

```
std::string query = std::accumulate(cols.begin(), cols.end(), 
    std::string("SELECT "), join(", ")) + " FROM some-table;";
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't bother to remove the trailing comma.
This is because you can select a constant and the SQL is still valid.

```
SELECT A FROM T

-- Is the same as 

SELECT A,1 FROM T

-- Apart from there is an extra column named 1 where each value is 1
```

So using the STL to make it compact:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

    std::stringstream           select;

    // Build select statement.
    select << "SELECT ";
    std::copy(col.begin(),col.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(select," , "));
    select << " 1 FROM TABLE PLOP";
```

Comment: Nice idea.  "Why didn't I think of that?"

Comment: It simplifies things nicely.  One could abuse the technique to do the column and values in an insert statement.

Comment: You're now bringing back extra data per row of returned data from the server though, which means extra traffic across the network. Take the extra billionth of a second to sort out your columns/commas rather than taking a hit that will multiply by the rows returned (which could be large).

Comment: (contd) Forgot to include... it would also possibly mean extra memory used on the server and on the client.

Comment: @Tom H: Yes there is a trade, as in all CS decisions. You must measure the increases in time/space and see if it is worth the reduced complexity (thus easier maintainability) in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The way I build up statements is usually:

```
pad = ""
stmt = "SELECT "

for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    stmt += pad + item[i]
    pad = ", "
}
```

This is relatively clean - it reassigns to pad each iteration, but that's trivial.  I've used any number of trivial variations on this, but it is the cleanest mechanism I know of.

Of course, there'll be someone else's answer to learn from too...

Comment: I use a similar method in my quick-and-dirty code, except I use a bool to check if I need to print the comma.

Comment: I was going to say that you end up with trailing commas.  Then I saw what you did there.  I'd say this code is a little "tricky" making it hard to maintain.

Comment: Also you end up with redundant assignments to 'pad' which if this is a high performance loop will be wasteful.

Comment: @John Dibling: depends on the language.  Most normally for me, in C, pad is a const char pointer, and the assignment is trivial.  The SQL statement is going to take far longer to execute than it does to create.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be so complicated.

```
string sql = "SELECT " + join(cols.begin(), cols.end(), ", ") + " FROM some_table";
```

where

```
template <typename I>
string join(I begin, I end, const string& sep){
   ostringstream out;
   for(; begin != end; ++begin){
      out << *begin;
      if(begin+1 != end) out << sep;
   }
   return out.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to belabor the point but take a look at boost::algorithm::join(). Here's an example in case you think that their documentation is too dense for words:

```
std::string
build_sql(std::vector<std::string> const& colNames,
          std::string const& tableName)
{
    std::ostringstream sql;
    sql << "SELECT "
        << boost::algorithm::join(colNames, std::string(","))
        << " FROM " << tableName;
    return sql.str();
}
```

When in doubt, look at Boost.org. They usually have a solution to most problems like this one already there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a generic join function to do this.  You can use the e.g. accumulate algorithm to join columns.

EDIT: **See [litb's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327010/using-a-vector-of-column-names-to-generate-a-sql-statement#327862)**; it's much less naïve.

```
// Untested
#include <numeric>

template<std::string separator>
struct JoinColumns {
    std::string operator()(Column a, Column b) {
        return a._name + separator + b._name;
    }

    // Too lazy to come up with a better name
    std::string inArray(T array) {
        stl::accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), std::string(), *this);
    }
};

selectSql += stl::accumulate(columns.begin(), columns.end(), std::string(), JoinColumns<", ">());
// or
selectSql += JoinColumns<", ">().inArray(columns);
```

You can get a cleaner syntax by using better wrappers, of course.

Comment: It is, but it's reusable for Column classes.  A better approach would be to have what field you want appended in the template somehow.

Comment: the idea is nice, but the implemtation wrong :) . there are no non-integral-nonpointer/nonreference-nontype template parameters. so you can't just make it accept std::string like above :p

Comment: Hah; I didn't know that.  I'm not too good with STL algorithms...  Sorry.

Comment: no worries. i've written it in my example how i would do it and given you credit for it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (z = 0; z < columns.size(); z++)
{
    if( z != 0 )
        selectSql += ", "; 
    selectSql += columns[z]._name;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it works.  It is similar to the second example I provided.